# how to make a phone call from twilio number to any other number which would facilitate the service of two people talking to each other

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token can be found at https://www.twilio.com/console
account_sid = "##################################"
auth_token = "################################"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# Start a phone call
call = client.calls.create(
    to="+9195555555555",
    from_="+15555555555",
    url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
)
print(call)
print(call.sid)
```

So here I am making a call from my Twilio number to another number but this does not allow me to have a conversation with the dialed number rather it just says whatever I wrote in the XML file which I have provided in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a way that works best for your use case for the link below.

[Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding)

Comment: my objective is to make a call using custom Alexa skill to a number provided by Alexa skill, so I was hoping if Twilio provided some sort of API to do so. I have registered for Twilio account and have a Twilio number, but cannot figure out a way to call a random number and have a conversation like any other cellular call.